# How to use vuetify in nuxt js as plugin?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I need to use vuetify in my nuxt js project as plugin. I've tried package [@nuxtjs/vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/vuetify) but get error

> Cannot assign to read only property 'base' of object '#'

[image]

I've install my nuxt project from official [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-vuetify-v0k7i) online playground in local server and on shared hosting. All the time I got the same error. I tried install node modules using `npm` and `yarn`. How I can add fresh vuetify version to last version of nuxt js as plugin with npm package [vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify)?

Comment: Were you able tor resolve this issue? I have tun into the same `Cannot assign to read only property 'base' of object '#'` issue with a project that uses nuxt and vuetify.

Comment: No, not yet succeeded. I also have such a problem with the project on `nuxtjs` + `vuetifyjs`. NPM package [@nuxtjs/vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/vuetify) still not updated on nuxt cli

Answer (score 7):

Install vuetify and @mdi/font

Create a file vuetify.js in your plugins folder with the following code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

import colors from './../config/colors'

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default ctx => {
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          ...colors
        },
        dark: {
          // colors
        }
      }
    }
  })
  ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify
  ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework
}
```

Edit nuxt.config.js file by adding vuetify to plugins like this

```js
{
  ...
  plugins: ['~plugins/vuetify.js'],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this with the following:

**npm install --save vuetify**

create a file **vuetify.js** in your plugins folder with the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Amend your **nuxt.config.js**:

```
   plugins: ['~plugins/vuetify.js'],
   build: {
     vendor: ['vuetify']
   }
```

Comment: How do you edit Vuetify specific settings such as your primary color?

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of this issue here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/268

Fixing custom colours and specifying options in external files seem to affect this.
If you have colours specified in the options, replace `primary: colors.blue` with `primary: colors.blue.base`.

Answer (score 0):

I have / had same issue. I simply made sure to use version 1.10.3 or below defined explicitly in package.json

"@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.10.3", (not with the ^1.10.3)

I also noticed any version over this also adds an "undefined" 404 to the end of every url request. I posted on Nuxt / CMTY but they have a user base of zero people who answer any questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose Vuetify as ur UI Framework when initial a Nuxt project**

Create a new file in `plugins/vuetify.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        light: true,
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: colors.blue.darken2,
                accent: colors.grey.darken3,
                secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
                info: colors.teal.lighten1,
                warning: colors.amber.base,
                error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
                success: colors.green.accent3
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Add the plugin config inside `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/vuetify.js'],
}
```

Restart server, `npm run dev`

An image example:
[vuetify.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEo9a.png)

Done!

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following steps in order and finally use Vuetify components:

**1- Setup vuetify**

```
yarn add vuetify@next sass
```

**2- Your `package.json` should now look similar to the following:**

```
// package.json
   "devDependencies": {
      "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.1"
    },
   "dependencies": {
      "sass": "^1.51.0",
      "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.1"
    }
```

**3- Creating your Vuetify plugin**

You must create this file in the plugin folder and put these codes inside it.

```
// plugins/vuetify.js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

**4- Configure Nuxt 2 or 3 to use our new plugin**

In this section, you should put these codes in the `nuxt.config.ts` file like this

```
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false,
    },
  },
})
```

5- Finally, in order to test that you have done the steps correctly, you can use this component in your code to see if Vuetify is installed correctly or not.

```
<v-btn>Button</v-btn>
```

**Tip: If you have done these steps or you want to use a new component, in many cases it is better to stop and restart your project once.**